# Letter permutations in 'COOLEEMEE'

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I'm considering the word 'COOLEEMEE'. The first part is asking the number of distinguishable permutations of these 9 letters, which should be $9!/(2!4!)=7560$.

The next part is asking how many distinguishable permutations of these 9 letters are there if consecutive O’s are forbidden?

(And the last part if how many distinguishable permutations if consecutive E’s are forbidden)

If we don't allow consecutive O's, then I think we could first permute the rest letters 'CLEEMEE', so there're $7!/4!$ ways. Then there're 8 spaces and I want to insert 2 O's, so should that be $\frac{7!}{4!}\binom{8}2$ in total?

Then similarly if consecutive E’s are forbidden, there're $\frac{5!}{2!}\binom{6}4$ total ways. Is my reasoning correct? I feel like I missed some cases but I'm not sure. I've seen some similar examples which used the inclusion-exclusion principle, but I don't know if I need to use that here. Thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we are looking for the number of words with no consecutive equal characters at all. Such words are called Smirnov or Carlitz words. See example III.24 *Smirnov words* in *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/books.html)* by Philippe Flajolet and Robert Sedgewick for more information.

A generating function for the number of Smirnov words over an $n$-ary alphabet is given by
\begin{align*}
\left(1-\frac{nz}{1+z}\right)^{-1}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> Here we consider an alphabet $\mathcal{V}=\{C,E,L,M,O\}$ with $n=5$ letters. Using $[z^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^k$ of a series we calculate
> \begin{align*}
> &\color{blue}{[CE^4LMO^2]\left(1-\sum_{a\in\mathcal{V}}\frac{a}{1+a}\right)^{-1}}\tag{2}\\
> &\qquad=[CE^4LMO^2]\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{a\in\mathcal{V}}\frac{a}{1+a}\right)^j\tag{3}\\
> &\qquad=[CE^4LMO^2]\sum_{j=5}^{9}\left(\sum_{a\in\mathcal{V}}\frac{a}{1+a}\right)^j\tag{4}\\
> &\qquad=[CE^4LMO^2]\sum_{j=5}^{9}\left(C+E\left(1-E+E^2-E^3\right)\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\left.+L+M+O(1-O)\right)^j\tag{5}\\
> &\qquad=120-1\,440+6\,300-11\,760+7\,560\tag{6}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{\qquad=780}
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with @trueblueanils answer.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we use the generating function (1). Since we want to identify specific powers of letters, we use a term $\frac{a}{1+a}$ for each letter in $\mathcal{V}$.
- In (3) we expand the geometric series.
- In (4) we observe that each term $\frac{a}{1+a}=a\left(1-a+a^2-\cdots\right)$ contains at least a factor $a$ so that the index range of of the series can be restricted to $j=5,\ldots,9$.
- In (5) we expand $\frac{a}{1+a}$ for each of the letters in $\mathcal{V}$. We skip all powers of letters, which do not contribute to $C,E^4,L,M,O^2$.
- In (6) we calculate the coefficients of the powers of $j=5,\ldots,9$ with some help of Wolfram Alpha.

Answer (score 3):

It is best to first find arrangements with no two $E's$ together, inserting the $E's$ in the dashes ($-$)

$-C-O-O-L-M-\;\;:\binom64\frac{5!}{2!} = 900$

From this, we need to subtract arrangements with the two $O's$ together,

$-C-[OO]-L-M-$, viz $\binom54 4! = 120$,

giving a final answer of $\;900-120=780$

### *Added to address OP's query*

I have taken the problem to mean that neither $E's\;nor\;O's$ should be together since you have mentioned inclusion-exclusion. If they are two separate sub-problems, one with no $E's$ together, another with no $O's$ together, you already know the procedure.

Comment: @IGY your methods are both correct. I think true blue anil interpreted the question differently, but they answered their interpretation correctly.

Comment: Thanks, we subtract arrangements with the two ′ together, is that because of the inclusion-exclusion principle?

Comment: In the first part when we separated the $E's$ the $O's$ were left either together or apart, so we need to subtract those arrangements **with** $E's$ **apart** in which $O's$ are together

Comment: I have added my interpretation of the question, and its rationale in the answer

Comment: @true blue anil Thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of help !

Answer (score 2):

> If we don't allow consecutive O's, then I think we could first permute the rest letters 'CLEEMEE', so there're 7!/4! ways. Then there're 8 spaces and I want to insert 2 O's, so should that be $\frac{7!}{4!}\binom{8}{2}$ in total?

If you consider 8 spaces (7 letters + 1) here, it means that you are adding the two Os as a unique block, so you should obtain $\frac{7!}{4!}\binom{8}{1}=\frac{7!}{4!}\cdot 8$, which are exactly the cases that you have to remove from the total.

This is basically the first step of the inclusion-exclusion principle: you're considering all the possible permutations and then you exclude the ones that have consecutive Os.

Otherwise if you consider 9 spaces, you have $\frac{7!}{4!}\binom{9}{2}=\frac{9!}{4!2!}$, which is basically splitting the initial problem into two separate steps.

The problem with the letter E is a bit more complicated instead, I can't guarantee this is the easiest solution:

Your goal is to remove once from the total every word that has at least two consecutive Es

you can start by removing the permutations of the block [EE] and the letters "COOLEEM". But then you notice that you also removed:

1. twice (one too much) the sequences that contain two couples of E (..EE...[EE]...,...[EE]...EE...)
2. twice (one too much) the sequences that contain at least three consecutive E (...E[EE]...,...[EE]E...)
3. thrice (two too many) the sequences that contain at least four consecutive E (...EE[EE]...,...E[EE]E...,...[EE]EE...).

You correct the first error by adding once the permutations of the symbols "[EE][EE]COOLM".

You try to correct the second error by adding once the permutations of the block [EEE] and the letters "COOLEM", but then again you notice that you're adding twice the words with 4 E (...E[EEE]...,...[EEE]E) thus amending your second and third error.

This is also somehow a non-canonical application of the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Why I could consider 9 spaces? Is the latter expression the same as the number of distinguishable permutations in the first part?

Comment: notice that the significant difference lays in the binomial coefficient: in the first problem you think like this:

For every previously assigned string of letters CLEEMEE, in how many ways can I add some Os?

You know that the order of the other letters is fixed, so you now have that, for every string, the way to insert the O is the number of the reciprocal positions of the letters and the Os, meaning "YYYYYYYOO" or "YYYYYYY[OO]", which are, respectively, $\binom{9}{2}$ and $\binom{8}{1}$